# Is it possible to set the default view scope for a calendar view in code?

Tags: wss-3.0, list-view, calendar

I can create a calendar view in code, however I have as yet been unable to figure out how to change the "Default Scope" (this is the name that appears in the user interface when editing a calendar view). The options in the user interface are Day, Week, or Month - Month being the default. I'd like to be able to change the default to something else, Week for example, but I cannot figure out how to do it, other than using the user interface.

Answer (score 1):

Try;

```
calView = new SPCalendarView();
calView.ViewType = "week";
```

Comment: I've seen that, but as far as I can tell that only relates to adding a view to a web part? If I have access to the SPView object, how do I then use your code?

Answer (score -1):

Try this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/608bc028-dd9a-49de-b774-c0f87dbe9c26/)

Answer (score -1):

You can't do it through API. By sending RPC call to owssvr.dll is the only other way other than UI. For complete solution, visit this link -

http://www.manvir.net/change-the-default-scope-of-sharepoint-calendar-view-to-week/

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. Also we  require disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.